# Compile old source code checking for _MSC_VER with new compiler in Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, compiler-errors, qt-creator

In my Qt project (Windows platform, using Qt Creator) I need to include an older third-party header file which checks for the MSVC compiler version:

```
# if !( _MSC_VER==1500 || _MSC_VER==1600 )
#       error Invalid compiler
#   endif
```

I am using the MSVC2019 compiler, which is according to this site https://dev.to/yumetodo/list-of-mscver-and-mscfullver-8nd at least 1920 or higher (depending on update).

Can I do anything to compile this? Removing or commenting of course, but I'm not sure if that's creating other problems... Is there maybe any flag which I can set in my .pro file to make the MSVC2019 compiler behave like an older compiler?

Comment: You can't use the old Qt binaries with a newer msvc if that is the goal. Qt would need to be recompiled but that would require a lot of work since QMake for these old versions does not support the newer compiler. If you are using Qt-4.X you probably need Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Now looking at the `if !( _MSC_VER==1500 || _MSC_VER==1600 )` I expect there is no hope to get this to work with Visual Studio 2019 as your compiler. These are Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 and c++03.